# Push segue animation moving to the left?

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I set up a navigation controller with 3 views. I used the push segue with a swipe gesture to mimic the iPhone home screen (pages of apps). It works properly but I noticed when the swipe to the right to go back a page the transition animation makes it look like its advancing a page. Any ideas on how I can get the push segue animation to make it move to the left?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a navigation controller for this.  You should either put your pages in a scroll view, or use a `UIPageViewController`.  Starting in iOS 6, you can set the page view controller's `transitionStyle` to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Better use unwindSegues they are very easy, I learnt to use them with this article: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/

And a Stackoverflow related: [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)